# cron job not mailing output of urlwatch

Tags: cron

I have one cron job like this:

```
* * * * * urlwatch | mail -s "job  changes" pc_xxx@msn.com
```

It mails every minute as expected. However when I alter the test html page on my local server it doesn't email the differences, just continues to mail a blank mail with the title 'job changes'.

When I paste the job to a prompt:

```
pc@dellbox:/$urlwatch | mail -s "job  changes" pc_xxx@msn.com
```

and run before/after changing the html, it emails the differences in the 2nd email as expected.

(pc is the owner of urls.txt and the cronjob was created by pc via crontab -e)

Why does the cron version not email the urlwatch output?

This is driving me batty...

Any/all help gratefully received.

ps couldn't create urlwatch as a new tag - need 1500 rep :(

**Update:**

If I split the command into two bits like this:

```
urlwatch > ~/.urlwatch/output.txt
 mail -s "output" pc_xxx@msn.com < ~/.urlwatch/output.txt
```

This works.

If I join the two statements with a pipe like this:

```
urlwatch > ~/.urlwatch/output.txt | mail -s "output" pc_xxx@msn.com < ~/.urlwatch/output.txt
```

I get a prompt IMMEDIATELY that says

```
Null message body; hope that's ok
```

I notice urlwatch takes 2 - 3 seconds to complete, and I understand shell commands wait for preceding commands to finish (unless you're using &?). Dunno if this is significant.

Also, I'm using sSMTP...

Comment: try this in linux terminal: `cat somefile.html | mail -s "job changes" pc_xxx@msn.com`

Comment: ok just tried it - file is emailed as content. What next...

Answer (score 3):

Use full path when calling urlwatch:

```
$ which urlwatch
/usr/bin/urlwatch
```

Then your cron have to be::

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/urlwatch | mail -s "job  changes" pc_xxx@msn.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `.urlwatch` directories under `/root/` as the program will look there to store its data

Comment: Nope, moved file to /root/.urlwatch/urls.txt and I get: Error: You need to create a urls.txt file first.

Place it in /home/pc/.urlwatch/urls.txt

Answer (score 0):

@askchipbug: your case looks very specific, but here are the things to do that may help:

-check /var/log/mail.err or /var/log/mail.log to find hints
-crontab user/permission
-some server strips content for not a good reason
-i use mailx it works fine for me and here is my cron job in crontab -e:

```
* * * * * urlwatch --urls=/var/www/html/urls.txt --hooks=/home/foo/hooks.py | mailx -v -r "bar@gmail.com" -s "This is the subject line" -S smtp="smtp.gmail.com:587" -S smtp-use-starttls -S smtp-auth=login -S smtp-auth-user="foo2@gmail.com" -S smtp-auth-password="bardaf16charsfoo" -S ssl-verify=ignore receipient@hotmail.com
```

- i found the info for heirloom-mailx client installation from here: http://www.binarytides.com/linux-mail-with-smtp/

hope it helps.